# Show/filter features based on field value in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have geoJSON file with an ID Field.

I would like to add an input box with where a user can enter a specific ID.

Based on this input only features with this ID would be displayed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I may achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine different stuffs. Here is a way to go:

1) The input search box:

Add an input field in your HTML DOM and add an event listener or a function (`addFeature(id)`) to it. When the user will type/select some ID, you need to trigger an action. You may need an autocompletion widget, as this [one](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). I'll assume you know how to make it. Otherwise, make some research! This is a pure HTML/JS question, so have also a look at stackoverflow.com.

2) Filter the geojson:

Then, when your action is triggered, you may display only the feautres with a certain `id` using the `pointToLayer` method, with something like:

```
var addFeature = function (id) {
  var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(yourGeojsonData, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        if (feature.ID == id) {
        return markerLayer = L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: // your icon styling function
        });
      }
    }
  }
  map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
 }
```

I don't have your code and I don't know how you load your geojson, so you'll surely have to modify this function! In addition, you'll probably have to remove old layers when performing a new search (using `map.removeLayer()`).

The relevant doc is here: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#geojson